# Subdialog's hWnd resets to NULL after the dialog is initialized

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have stuck with the following problem. I have a main dialog that has some controls. It also displays several subdialogs (as subcontrols) that are set as a pointer members with their `ID`s. I create these dialogs with their `ID`s via `CreateControl` during `OnInitDialog`. Yesterday it **worked very well**. Today, I decided to add some controls to subdialogs and caught a problem.

That's how I create subdialogs in the main dialog durig `OnInitDialog`:

```
if (m_pNewObjDlg != NULL) m_pNewObjDlg->Create(m_nNewObjDlgID, this);
if (m_pSharedObjDlg != NULL) m_pSharedObjDlg->Create(m_nSharedObjDlgID, this);
```

That's how I set the subdialogs outside from one of my routines:

```
dlgSelectSharedObject.SetNewPageObject(&dlgSelectNewTableDialog, CSelectNewTableDialog::IDD);
dlgSelectSharedObject.SetSharedPageObject(&dlgSelectSharedTable, CSelectSharedTableDialog::IDD);
```

I see that `OnInitDialog` and `DoDataExchange` of the two subdialogs work well, subdialogs' `m_hWnd`s are set, `GetDlgItem` methods return valid values. But when the execution comes back to main dialog's `OnInitDialog` I see that `m_hWnd` values of `pNewObjDlg` and `pSharedObjDlg` are `NULL`. I don't know how that could happen. I double checked the `ID`s, they don't overlap. As a result I get an `ASSERT` with nothing displayed except main dialog with its controls. Just any thoughts?

Comment: what controls you have in your sub-dialogs? are there any OCX controls?

Comment: @cha I'n not using any unsual controls like OCX and extensions, everything is just buttons, labels and list boxes.

Comment: I guess it is something with `ID`s.

Comment: No, `ID`s seem to be OK. What is the reason why `m_hWnd` is reset to `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. When data was loading to the controls within `DoDataExchange` I occasionally called `Fail`. It was a combo box without items because `DoDataExchange` was called from base class before combo box's initialization. It wasn't expected by the logic and thus `Fail` was called. It lead to the destruction of these child windows.